# Why this constructor function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I'm stuck on this exercise about Constructor Function: 
Declare a `Sandwich` constructor function that takes three parameters:
1. `bread` (string) - the type of bread for the sandwich (e.g. "Wheat")
2. `meat` (array) - the meats to put on the sandwich
   (e.g. `[]` for a vegetarian sandwich!)
3. `vegetables` (array) - the vegetables to include in the sandwich

I tried with this code but it doesn't pass the exercise:

```
function Sandwich(bread, meat, vegetables){  
    this.bread = "Wheat";
    this.meat = ["chicken", "hamburger"];
    this.vegetables = ["tomatoes", "potatoes", "onions"];
}

new Sandwich();
```

Comment: You are ignoring your parameters...

Comment: What should be the end result?

Comment: The whole point of a *constructor* function is that is *constructs* an object instance and returns it to you. Not only are you not passing `bread`, `meat`, and `vegetables` arguments to the function, but you aren't capturing the returned object reference - you're just invoking the function, in which case you shouldn't be using a constructor function in the first place.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The idea of having parameters on the constructor is for setting the corresponding properties. Not setting hard coded values. Try:

```
function Sandwich(bread, meat, vegetables){  
    this.bread = bread;
    this.meat =meat;
    this.vegetables =vegetables;
}
```

Comment: And, the idea of a *constructor* function is to construct a new object instance. Your answer doesn't address this.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Sandwich(bread, meat, vegetables){  
    this.bread = bread;
    this.meat = meat;
    this.vegetables = vegetables;
}

const meatSandwich = new Sandwich("Wheat", ["chicken", "hamburger"], ["tomatoes", "potatoes", "onions"]);
```

Comment: While this calls the function correctly, it doesn't capture the returned object reference, which defeats the purpose of a constructor function. It might as well just be `Sandwich("Wheat", ["chicken", "hamburger"], ["tomatoes", "potatoes", "onions"]);`

Comment: @ScottMarcus , I assumed this was implicit. Gonna assign the reference to an object, just for the sake of it.

Comment: Your answer really should be more than the correct code. Answers on Stack Overflow should be accompanied by an explanation of the problem(s) and an explanation of the solution(s). Since the OP didn't assign the resulting object anywhere, it's clear that it wasn't implicit to do so.

Comment: Any reason why assigning a default empty array by default to meat, but not to vegetable? Assuming that the OP is a novice, this will only make him/her confused.

Comment: @Mohayemin, originally had it because the OP stated that the sandwitch might be vegetarian. Of course there are many ways how to tackle this issue. Simplified for more clearance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you totally missed the idea. You are supposed to assign the values passed through constructor to the object.

```
function Sandwich(bread, meat, vegetables){  
    this.bread = bread;
    this.meat = meat;
    this.vegetables = vegetables;
}

var mySandwich = new Sandwich("Wheat", ["chicken", "hamburger"], ["tomatoes", "potatoes", "onions"]);
```

now do what you want to do with `mySandwich` object.

Comment: While this calls the function correctly, it doesn't capture the returned object reference, which defeats the purpose of a constructor function. It might as well just be `Sandwich("Wheat", ["chicken", "hamburger"], ["tomatoes", "potatoes", "onions"]);`

Answer (score 0):

You invoke a Function, but you should create different objects using the same constructor.

```js
function Sandwich(bread, meat, vegetables){  
    this.bread = bread;
    this.meat =meat;
    this.vegetables =vegetables;
}
```